# Need help solving integral-$ \int x^2 (e^x)^3 \sin x \mathrm dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

i have a nasty integral to solve. i tried using the parts method but it just blew off.Can anyone provide a solution much better than what i have done here?.

$$\int x^2 (e^x)^3 \sin x\, \mathrm dx$$

Comment: $(e^x)^3=e^xe^xe^x=e^{3x}$

Answer (score 4):

Just integrate by parts:
$$\int x^2\left(e^x\right)^3\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x=\int u\,\mathrm{d}v\text{ where }u=x^2,\,\mathrm{d}v=e^{3x}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Note you may want to tackle $v=\int e^{3x}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x$ using parts as well, or you could (of course) play with Euler's identity.

Comment: thanks!! that feels better :D!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach.  Put
$$\Phi(t) = \int e^{3tx}\sin(x)\, dx.$$
Now resolve the integral by integration by parts.

Next, apply Leibnitz's rule for differentiation of the integral to find $\Phi''(t)$ and you are on home base.